# Javascript / jQuery change event only for clicks

Tags: jquery

Although I'm pretty sure there is probably a duplicate question somewhere I couldn't find it. So excuse me in advance if there is one.

I have a  dropdown list to which I bind a change event with jQuery. The issue here is that when you select the dropdown (no change) and then start typing, most browsers do some sort of autocomplete style selection of options. For each time the value changes, this hits my method. This is fine, but I'd like to filter out these additional events and only react to a 'real' selection, either on click (mouse) or after selecting a value and hitting enter.

I could change to using onkeypress / onclick, but then I'd have to write additional logic to check whether the value actually changed or not. So is there a nifty way of combining all of this and have the select only react to proper selections, leaving out the autocomplete-style events the browser initiates? I checked whether the change event object contains anything of use to find out what initiated the change, doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This behaviour is required for accessibility reasons (ie. those who browse only via the keyboard). I don't see why it's an issue though - a selection is still being made and the `change()` event being fired is perfectly valid behaviour.

Comment: Yes I know that. The event is copying the 'selected' value to another list though, and I don't want that to happen whilst the user is typing in values. The other solution would be an additional button which has to be clicked, but that's an additional step I don't really want to bother the user with.

Comment: There should always be a button to perform the action. Performing an action immediately after a selection has been made is just a convenience.

Comment: Yeah well there's customer requirements to create inconveniences ;) If it's not doable then we'll switch to a button, but it's perfectly doable to react to only enter + click, just trying to find a nicer way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the event's 'which' property. 
e.which will give undefined for mouse click and will give 13 for enter key press.

Comment: Nope, cannot use that. e.which returns undefined for both clicks as well as letters being typed as part of the autocomplete.